# Efficiently webscraping a website without an api?

Tags: web-scraping

Considering that most languages have webscraping functionality either built in, or made by others, this is more of a general web-scraping question.

I have a site in which I would like to pull information from about 6 different pages. This normally would not be that bad; unfortunately though, the information on these pages changes roughly every ten seconds, which could mean over 2000 queries an hour (which is simply not okay). There is no api to the website I have in mind either. Is there any possible efficient way to get the amount of information I need without flooding them with requests, or am I out of luck?

Comment: Would the users of your site  notice if the results updated slower?

Answer (score 0):

At best, the site might return you an `HTTP 304 Not Modified` in its header when you make a request - indicating that you need not download the page, as nothing has changed. If the site is set up to do so, this might help decrease bandwidth, but would still require the same number of requests.

If there's a consistent update schedule, then at least you know when to make the requests - but you'll still have to *ask* (i.e.: make a request) to find out what information has changed.